# Java parser to read nested and lengthy xml

Tags: java, xml-parsing, nested

I have gone through many Stackoverflow pages and web to decide on parser which fits in for my requirement.
I need to read nested and big xml files in java , so DOM parser would not be good fit . My xml looks like below(snippet)-

```
   <products>
        <product>
            <productCode></productCode>
            <Code>3002191</Code>
            <anotherCode></anotherCode>
            <entityName>entityName value</entityName>
            <entityName2>entityName value</entityName2>
            <Type>value</Type>
            <List>1</List>
            <SecondCode>124</SecondCode>
            <docInfo>
                <name>value1</name>
                <docName>value</docName>
                <docId>045</docId>
                <type>Full Name</type>
                <class>value</class>
                <docCode>123</docCode>
                <date>07/12/2016</date>
                <countries>
                    <country>India</country>
                </countries>
                <language>EN</language>

            </docInfo>
            <docInfo>
                <name>value1</name>
                <docName>value</docName>
                <docId>1219</docId>
                <type>Full Name</type>
                <class>value</class>
                <docCode>123</docCode>
                <date>07/12/2016</date>
                <countries>
                    <country>India</country>
                </countries>
                <language>EN</language>

            </docInfo>
</product>
<product>
..
</product>
</products>
```

Requirement: I need to store products information into list of hashmap for further processing with other xmls. Firstly, I thought to use Stax api to do this.But element docInfo has countries element so there can be multiple document for many countries and I cant parse backward to save another document(which has same document info but with country) . Please let me know if I am clear enough

Please let me know which parser will be good to handle this situation , i do not have any schemas for this xml.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a big amount of XML, the best is to use SAX : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

You implement the ContentHandler interface and you can put the logic you need when parsing the docInfo and subsequent countries.

Comment: thank you for your comment, what about JAXB? Can we use it in such situation?